# What techniques are available to do P2P in the browser?

Tags: javascript, flash, html, p2p, soundcloud-stratus

What options does a web developer currently have for implementing client-side peer-to-peer systems in the web browser? Some hypothetical examples might be a file-sharing service that bypasses the web-server after clients find eachother, or a chat service.

#### What I know about:

- the site chatroulette uses
  some flash technology as discussed
  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643291/architecture-of-chatroulette).
- And I am also aware of [Opera
  Unity](http://www.opera.com/press/releases/2009/06/16/) which extends the browser
  model to encompass both a client and
  a server, as well as this firefox [plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pow-plain-old-webserver/) which works similarly
- I also just came across [this blog
  post](http://www.nonblocking.io/2008/12/universalcomet-making-every-client.html) related to the Joose js
  framework, but am not yet sure if it
  is relevant here.
- Support for this *kind of thing* seems like it might or might not be supported by websockets in  HTML5 and has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628565/html5-vs-flash-full-comparison-chart-anywhere) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032006/will-html5-allow-web-apps-to-make-peer-to-peer-http-connections) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118272/do-websockets-allow-for-p2p-browser-to-browser-communication).

Comment: Fun question, I'm very curious to see what we find here. (+1)

Comment: Just to point out, websockets are part of JavaScript NOT HTML (which is the new name for HTML5)

Comment: Would vote to reopen if I could; the answer is the DataChannel API.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218250/transfering-json-between-browsers-with-webrtc

Comment: Thanks psema4. I'm not sure why it was closed. The only explanation is that this will elicit "extended discussion" in that the answer is likely to change over time. Perhaps it should be a community wiki?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion jberryman; I've flagged the question for review.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you to take a look at [RTMFP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Media_Flow_Protocol) in Adobe Flash Player - it seems you can build something close to what you're asking with it.

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for the same thing, this library looks apealing:
[rtmfp-api/](http://h3xstream.github.com/rtmfp-api/)