# Transferring JSON between browsers with WebRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I was excited by the prospect of WebRTC when I heard about it initially.  It sounded like websockets but without a server.  Unfortunately, all of the tutorials I have been able to find have stressed the video and and audio aspects of WebRTC.  I can't find anything about sending text/data/JSON between browsers.  Could you help me write a simple hello world of sorts, just sending some data from one browser to another with WebbRTC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a stab in the dark, but the latest Web API editors draft has a `DataChannel` interface as part of the [Peer-to-Peer Data API](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html#peer-to-peer-data-api).

However, the current [Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-webrtc-20120209/) does not have this API, so possibly it is very new and as-yet unimplemented.

Comment: I saw a blogpost that said that WebRTC can already send data, but it focused on video chat.  It sounded like sending data is already available, but I couldn't find the way it was implemented.

Comment: What makes the Peer to Ppeer data api diffrent from PeerConnection?  It looks like, or at least in the example given in the april 18th draft, both can send messages without a server.

Comment: `PeerConnection` is *connection-layer*, and can't be used directly to send data. Once you have a `PeerConnection`, you attach `MediaStreams` to it which provide data to send or receive. Streams are one-way, it seems. But the Data API adds a new method to `PeerConnection` which returns a bidirectional `DataChannel`, which can both send and receive arbitrary data. `MediaStreams` are not built like that.

Comment: One-way as in that you can only set up a receiving or sending connection, but not both?

Comment: Matt, you seem to be confused. You can open a *connection* (like a road--something data can travel on which is bidirectional), and you can send data that conforms to the `MediaStream` interface (unidirectional, multi-track data, like audio or video), but you cannot arbitrarily put bytes together and send them, nor send data back and forth on the same channel (not *connection*: *channel*) without the `DataChannel` interface.

Comment: thanks for helping me clear that up, I'll have to wait a few months for the browsers to implement these apis, but I'm excited about the possibilities by the time that they do

Answer (score 6):

DataChannel has now been implemented in Firefox (18+) and Chrome (25+), though it's still early days.

For more information see the HTML5 Rocks article [Getting Started with WebRTC](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#toc-rtcdatachannel).

Comment: Is the DataChannel in Google Chrome according to the spec. Because [here](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=1408) it says SCTP is pending. Then is it using UDP or TCP?

Comment: Chrome currently only offers unreliable (UDP) datachannels, pending SCTP support.  Firefox offers both unreliable (UDP) and reliable (TCP).

Answer (score 3):

This functionality is not yet implemented in any shipping WebRTC implementation. As other posters have indicated, there now is a DataChannel API in the latest WebRTC editors' draft, but the protocol for this is still being worked on. Expect to see this API live in Chrome and Firefox later this year.

Comment: So you're able to open a connection between browsers, but you can't send data yet?

Comment: You can send `MediaStreams` only, which is data, but not arbitrary data constructed by the application, which is what you want to do. Also, the application can't send anything back in response--it can only send its own `MediaStreams` unrelated to the ones you are sending.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but because I started to learn webRTC, I will attempt to answer it.

First of all, some misconception:

> It sounded like websockets but without a server

There is no way ANY data can be transferred between WebRTC peers before some information (Media session management, Nodes’ network configuration/multimedia capabilities) has been properly exchanged and negotiated. To do this you need a server and [signalling](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/) (which is not a part of webRTC: you can implement it the way you want).

When the signaling is done, you need to create [RTCPeerConnection](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/) with something like this:

```
if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) {
   RTCPeerConnection = webkitRTCPeerConnection;
} else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia){
   RTCPeerConnection = mozRTCPeerConnection;
   RTCSessionDescription = mozRTCSessionDescription;
   RTCIceCandidate = mozRTCIceCandidate;
}
```

and then:

```
var connection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
```

After this you can add your data channel to this PeerConnection:

```
var dataChannel = connection.createDataChannel("channelName",{ reliable: true });
```

When this is done you can just call `sendChannel.send('Any data you want');` and this will send any data you want.

If anything, I found [this book really helpful](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449371876). It leaves a lot of unanswered questions, but for the first start it is good.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Matt already know, but for google guests: Yes, you can, useing DataChannels.

On your side:

```
channel = somePeerConnection.createDataChannel("a Label");
channel.onopen = function() { channel.send("any thing") };
```

On the other side:

```
somePeerConnection.ondatachannel = function (evt) {
   evt.channel.onmessage = function (evt) {
       alert( evt.data );
   };
};
```

See this examples:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#examples
- https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/11/progress-update-on-webrtc-for-firefox-on-desktop/#file-datachannels-js-LC12

Comment: the second link you posted is a 404

Answer (score 1):

http://peerjs.com/ is evolving and gives you a websocket like syntax for p2p Data transfer between browser instances

Answer (score 0):

As Justin indicated, the protocol and API are still being nailed down; at the latest IETF I submitted a draft for the minor protocol underneath the JS API.  The final form will likely be very close to the current proposal in the editor's draft, but you'll likely need to wait on "onopened" from the receiving side as well.

The API is modeled on the WebSocket api to ease moving code from a WebSocket implementation to DataChannels, though not all items in WebSocket carry over (such as url), and obviously DataChannel adds a number of abilities not in WebSockets having to do with unreliable or partly-reliable data.

Comment: I got a WebSockets mechanism working for my website, and while it's better than AJAX, I thought it would be really cool (not to mention infinitely awesomer for my server I didn't have to transfer so much data) to have WebRTC cut down my costs to simply hosting the website and database, and nothing more.