# Push notification using webRTC

Tags: android, notifications, push, webrtc

I am working on an android project where I need to implement *Push notification* msg from my own server (that I have created).

I need to implement it using [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) but after much exploring I have come to know that WebRTC is for voice call. Is my assumption is correct, if not where i can find some tutorials to implement Push Notification using WebRTC?

Comment: WebRTC is designed primarily for media streams connectivity ---- however ---- APIs also enable us share screens, data channels (text and files) etc. ---- browsers are tending to support data channels soon ---- Did you tried something else? – Like: http://pusher.com/tutorials/html5_realtime_push_notifications

Comment: @MuazKhan I have tried pusher and got it working successfully.But due to certain reasons i am asked to explore about WebRTC.do u know any tutorial on implementing  WebRTC on android devices.

Comment: Did you check this - https://github.com/lukeweber/webrtc-jingle-client --- the demo: --- https://github.com/lukeweber/webrtc-demo-files

Answer (score 2):

WebRTC won't help you in implementing what you are trying to achieve.

WebRTC deals with real time communications over the web, where its current main focus is voice and video.

Pure data will be added later on, but even then I doubt you will achieve the expected result with it.

The main premise of WebRTC is one where you know what 2 participants are within a connection, they already know that they are about to communicate, and then webRTC kicks in to send the actual data.

Comment: Data is possible by using `RTCDataChannel`. Useful for real-time chat, games, transfer file. That is what I am looking for. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/ http://stackoverflow.com/a/10218470/186334

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to check out RFC6455 HTML5 WebSockets for lightweight bi-directional communication which seems to fit your use case better than WebRTC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use websockets to create push notifications. I wrote [a tutorial](http://blog.felixhagspiel.de/index.php/posts/create-your-own-videochat-application-with-html-and-javascript) for a WebRTC application where I also explain how to set up a websocket server for signaling. You can use that part of the tutorial (starting at "The Server") to share notifications and just ignore the rest of the WebRTC stuff.