# video conference chatting

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-4.0, video-conferencing

What is the procedure to invite users for video chatting and allow them as well as myself to view live video streaming from  webcam ?do i have to provide my ip address and access their ip address to access the webcam?what are the network protocals to be used? couldnt find myself any relevant links and resources. would be happy if i get any pointers related to this?i am developing asp.net web application with silverlight using c#.

thank you

Answer (score 3):

**Please try these links.** hope it helps to an extent

[P2P streaming- MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/fb4262dd-fae2-498a-a61b-fdc77a1ed2e4/)

[Voice Chat - Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/VoiceChatApplicationInCS.aspx)

[Silverlight + WCF](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/205342/481277.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Similar question here? [Architecture of chatroulette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643291/architecture-of-chatroulette)

> AFAIK ChatRoulette uses a new set of
>   API's in Flash Player 10.1 codenamed
>   Stratus, which allows for peer-to-peer
>   connections between Flash Player
>   instances.
>
> So instead of the video and audio
>   streams being pushed up to a special
>   streaming server, like FMS or Red5
>   unique ID's are shared and peers
>   connect directly to each other.
>
> This has great possibilities to reduce
>   server load for live streaming of
>   events where 1 connection to a server
>   stream can be shared between near
>   neighbours.
>
> Can you imagine the hosting bills for
>   something like ChatRoulette if Stratus
>   wasn't pushing the streams directly
>   between the peers?!
>
> If you're interested in knowing more
>   check out Stratus' section on Adobe
>   lads:
>   http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/stratus/

Maybe there is a similar technology in silverlight?